# Hashicorp Vault on k8s: Error initializing listener of type tcp: error loading TLS cert: open : no such file or directory

Tags: ssl, kubernetes, configuration, kubernetes-helm, hashicorp-vault

I configured the self-signed TLS following [this issue](https://github.com/hashicorp/vault-helm/issues/140).

After installing NOT in standalone but rather using storage "raft" + ha as in this [beginner tutorial](https://learn.hashicorp.com/tutorials/vault/kubernetes-raft-deployment-guide?in=vault/kubernetes), I'm getting in each pod installed those errors:

> Error initializing listener of type tcp: error loading TLS cert: open: no such file or directory

I don't understand. I only created the secret in k8s and didn't now upload and files, from where do it takes them? What is this path `/vault/userconfig/vault-server-tls/`?

If I do: `kubectl get secret vault-server-tls -n vault-foo -o yaml` I'm getting:

```
apiVersion: v1
data:
  vault.ca: LS0t.....GSUNBVEUtLS0tLQo=
  vault.crt: LS0tLS1CRUdJ....LS0tLUVORCBDRVJUSUZJQ0FURS0tLS0tCg==
  vault.key: LS0tLS1CR....S0tDQo=
kind: Secret
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration: |     {"apiVersion":"v1","data":{"vault.ca":"LS0tLS1CR...FWS0tLS0tDQo="},"kind":"Secret","metadata":{"annotations":{},"creationTimestamp":"2021-01-21T09:34:31Z","managedFields":[{"apiVersion":"v1","fieldsType":"FieldsV1","fieldsV1":{"f:data":{".":{},"f:vault.ca":{},"f:vault.crt":{},"f:vault.key":{}},"f:type":{}},"manager":"kubectl.exe","operation":"Update","time":"2021-01-21T09:34:31Z"}],"name":"vault-server-tls","namespace":"vault-foo","selfLink":"/api/v1/namespaces/vault-foo/secrets/vault-server-tls","uid":"845b856e-d934-46dd-b094-ca75084542cd"},"type":"Opaque"}
  creationTimestamp: "2021-01-21T09:34:31Z"
  managedFields:
  - apiVersion: v1
    fieldsType: FieldsV1
    fieldsV1:
      f:data:
        .: {}
        f:vault.ca: {}
        f:vault.crt: {}
        f:vault.key: {}
      f:metadata:
        f:annotations:
          .: {}
          f:kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration: {}
      f:type: {}
    manager: kubectl.exe
    operation: Update
    time: "2021-01-21T09:39:10Z"
  name: vault-server-tls
  namespace: vault-foo
  resourceVersion: "62302347"
  selfLink: /api/v1/namespaces/vault-foo/secrets/vault-server-tls
  uid: 845b856e-d934-46dd-b094-ca75084542cd
type: Opaque
```

The helm:

```
# Vault Helm Chart Value Overrides
global:
  enabled: true
  tlsDisable: false

injector:
  enabled: true
  # Use the Vault K8s Image https://github.com/hashicorp/vault-k8s/
  image:
    repository: "hashicorp/vault-k8s"
    tag: "latest"

  resources:
      requests:
        memory: 256Mi
        cpu: 250m
      limits:
        memory: 256Mi
        cpu: 250m

server:
  # Use the Enterprise Image
  image:
    repository: "hashicorp/vault-enterprise"
    tag: "1.5.0_ent"

  # These Resource Limits are in line with node requirements in the
  # Vault Reference Architecture for a Small Cluster
  resources:
    requests:
      memory: 8Gi
      cpu: 2000m
    limits:
      memory: 16Gi
      cpu: 2000m

  # For HA configuration and because we need to manually init the vault,
  # we need to define custom readiness/liveness Probe settings
  readinessProbe:
    enabled: true
    path: "/v1/sys/health?standbyok=true&sealedcode=204&uninitcode=204"
  livenessProbe:
    enabled: true
    path: "/v1/sys/health?standbyok=true"
    initialDelaySeconds: 60

  # extraEnvironmentVars is a list of extra environment variables to set with the stateful set. These could be
  # used to include variables required for auto-unseal.
  extraEnvironmentVars:
    VAULT_CACERT: /vault/userconfig/vault-server-tls/vault.crt

  # extraVolumes is a list of extra volumes to mount. These will be exposed
  # to Vault in the path .
  #extraVolumes:
  #  - type: secret
  #    name: tls-server
  #  - type: secret
  #    name: tls-ca
  #  - type: secret
  #    name: kms-creds
  extraVolumes:
    - type: secret
      name: vault-server-tls   
  
  # This configures the Vault Statefulset to create a PVC for audit logs.
  # See https://www.vaultproject.io/docs/audit/index.html to know more
  auditStorage:
    enabled: true

  standalone:
    enabled: false

  # Run Vault in "HA" mode.
  ha:
    enabled: true
    replicas: 3
    raft:
      enabled: true
      setNodeId: true

      config: |
        ui = true
        listener "tcp" {
          address = "[::]:8200"
          cluster_address = "[::]:8201"
          #tls_disable = 1
        }

        storage "raft" {
          path = "/vault/data"
            retry_join {
            leader_api_addr = "http://vault-0.vault-internal:8200"
            leader_ca_cert_file = "/vault/userconfig/vault-server-tls/vault.crt"
            leader_client_cert_file = "/vault/userconfig/vault-server-tls/vault.crt"
            leader_client_key_file = "/vault/userconfig/vault-server-tls/vault.key"
          }
          retry_join {
            leader_api_addr = "http://vault-1.vault-internal:8200"
            leader_ca_cert_file = "/vault/userconfig/vault-server-tls/vault.crt"
            leader_client_cert_file = "/vault/userconfig/vault-server-tlsr/vault.crt"
            leader_client_key_file = "/vault/userconfig/vault-server-tls/vault.key"
          }
          retry_join {
            leader_api_addr = "http://vault-2.vault-internal:8200"
            leader_ca_cert_file = "/vault/userconfig/vault-server-tls/vault.crt"
            leader_client_cert_file = "/vault/userconfig/vault-server-tls/vault.crt"
            leader_client_key_file = "/vault/userconfig/vault-server-tls/vault.key"
          }
        }

        service_registration "kubernetes" {}

# Vault UI
ui:
  enabled: true
  serviceType: "LoadBalancer"
  serviceNodePort: null
  externalPort: 8200

  # For Added Security, edit the below
  #loadBalancerSourceRanges:
  #   - < Your IP RANGE Ex. 10.0.0.0/16 >
  #   - < YOUR SINGLE IP Ex. 1.78.23.3/32 >
```

Comment: Your config appears to have a typo: `leader_client_cert_file = "/vault/userconfig/vault-server-tlsr/vault.crt"` has `tlsr` in the directory name

Comment: thanks! i fixed it but still getting the same error :
Error initializing listener of type tcp: error loading TLS cert: open : no such file or directory